# Can I configure Autofac to use dependencies from my Azure Functions bindings?

Tags: inversion-of-control, azure-functions, autofac

We use Autofac for our API projects. Porting out functions over has been on our todo list since Azure Functions announced support for Autofac. We already share a lot of services / repositories, but currently `new()` them up in the function body, which is a bit verbose.

I took a swing at it today, but am finding that I'm just being more verbose elsewhere. Specifically, I realised that I was writing a lot of code to replicate the functionality offered by bindings.

As an example, take the `[CosmosDB()]` binding attribute, which basically gives one a working, authenticated ("read-to-eat") `DocumentClient` in a single line.

When I'm using Autofac, it's necessary to manually read several settings from the config and to initialise a KeyVault client, etc...

Can I have my cake and eat it? Is there some way to register dependencies from my bindings so that they are available for Autofac to supply to my services etc.?

Answer (score 0):

For Functions created in Azure Functions V2, you should be able to register your dependencies via dependency injection. Here's a blog post on how to do this for Autofac: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Azure-Functions-Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac

Comment: Ah, apologies if my question wasn't clear. We've already implemented Autofac in our Azure functions. I'm looking for a way to register dependencies provided by the function bindings so we can use them in our downstream services,

Comment: Note: your link point to a fork of Autofac, not the official branch.